# How to handle Ignored lists of packages got with sudo apt-get update?

Tags: apt, updates

Running the command `sudo apt-get update | grep Ign` in bash of my Ubuntu 15.10 I got the following:

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
```

Should I worry about these ignored lists of packages?
Should I worry about duplication of these lists?
How can I fix it?

**UPD:**
The content of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
```

**UPD2**

I have two additional repos:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list
```

The content of first one is

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The content of the second one is

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

If I comment the last string then the duplication disappears. Thus, I guess, there is no problem with the duplication.

Comment: Not every repository provides translation-data for localization. No reason to worry about.

Comment: Re. "Should I worry about duplication of these lists?", I guess people would need to see the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to get a clue.